# FlashDevelop - change default choice for autocompleted classes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, ide, flashdevelop

Sometimes there is a name conflict between classes in two different libraries, but I almost exclusively use one over the other. Unfortunately, the one I am using is not showing up as the first entry and I have to press the down arrow to pick it.

How can I change the one that shows up first by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible using FlashDevelop.  You can see a response from the developer in this forum post with a similar question here: [Sorting Types in CodeCompletion](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7546)